# iMac turned on after repairing, but didn’t start again after that

Tags: imac, power

My iMac (late 2014, 27 inch) stopped working so, I opened it up and figured out that the problem was in the power supply. I replaced the power supply and started it again, 3 LEDs were on (first 3 from bottom, I hadn’t connected the display) the iMac chime played but then I was unable to turn it off via the power button, so I pulled the plug. Then I tried to start it back up again but only the bottom most LED was on and the power button wasn’t doing anything. What could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how the LEDs are numbered, but I would've consulted [Repair Preservation Group Wiki](https://repair.wiki)

> - LED #1 powers on, when power button is pressed it blinks only without
>   life
>
>   - I had this case and it was missing PM_SLP_S4_L. A bad resistor
>     was acting weird (below average) was replaced and issue was fixed. It
>     was R1215 powering PCH_DSWVRMEN.
>   - Can also occur with a dead or below threshold CMOS battery based on the schematics it should be 3.3v.
> - LED #1 is on, when power button is pressed it blinks and no further action
>
>   - Short on 12V_S0 power rail - machine starts boot process then stops when it sees there is a problem with the S0 rail and tries again. Inject voltage into the shorted rail starting at 1V and monitor using thermal camera to find where the faulty cap is. Remove offending cap and replace to resolve.

https://repair.wiki/w/2014_iMac_27%22

Answer (score 0):

My advice is reconnect every single thing you touched and then set aside what repair you made and treat it like a brand new - Mac won’t power on and go through every triage step for that for your model.

1. Quick steps (reset SMC, disconnect all accessories, document what happens internally when power is connected before attempting to press the power button or short the power on leads on the main board)
2. Make a minimal boot system
3. Begin replacing parts one by one based on the symptoms on the minimal system